# reload configmap in Spring Boot 3 does not work

Tags: spring-boot, configmap, spring-boot-3, spring-cloud-kubernetes

Reload configmap to get properties is working well with Spring Boot 2.7,
but it does not with Spring Boot 3.x.
Anyone can help me?
This is my codebase, https://github.com/lkseoqkr/configmaptest/tree/main

## environment & dependency

- minikube
- Java17
- org.springframework.boot 3.0.9
- io.spring.dependency-management 1.1.3
- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.4
- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-all

## application.properties

```
spring.application.name=configmaptest
spring.main.cloud-platform=kubernetes
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true

spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.name=configmaptest
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.namespace=default

spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.all-namespaces=true
spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.namespaces=default

spring.cloud.kubernetes.reload.monitoring-config-maps=true
spring.cloud.kubernetes.reload.enabled=true
spring.cloud.kubernetes.reload.strategy=refresh

management.endpoint.refresh.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

logging.level.org.springframework.cloud=debug

configmap-property.username=configmap-test_user
configmap-property.id=1234
configmap-property.enable=true

refresh-property.username=refresh-test_user
refresh-property.id=4321
refresh-property.enable=true
```

## Application.java

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigmaptestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigmaptestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

## Controller.java

```
@RefreshScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
@RestController
public class ConfigmaptestController {

  @Autowired
  private ConfigmapProperties configmapProperties;

  @GetMapping("configmap-properties")
  public String getConfigmapProperties() {
    return String.format("username: %s, id: %d, enable: %b",
        configmapProperties.getUsername(), configmapProperties.getId(), configmapProperties.getEnable());
  }
}
```

## Configuration.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "configmap-property")
@Data
public class ConfigmapProperties {
  private String username;

  private Integer id;

  private Boolean enable;
}
```

## deploy.yaml for minikube

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: configmaptest
      name: configmaptest
      namespace: default
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: http
          port: 8080
          targetPort: 8080
          nodePort: 30950
      selector:
        app: configmaptest
      type: LoadBalancer
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: ServiceAccount
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: configmaptest
      name: configmaptest
      namespace: default
  - apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: ClusterRoleBinding
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: configmaptest
      name: configmaptest
      namespace: default
    roleRef:
      kind: ClusterRole
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      name: configmaptest
    subjects:
      - kind: ServiceAccount
        name: configmaptest
        namespace: default
  - apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: ClusterRole
    metadata:
      namespace: default
      name: configmaptest
    rules:
      - apiGroups: [""]
        resources: ["configmaps", "pods", "services", "endpoints", "secrets"]
        verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: configmaptest
      namespace: default
    data:
      application.properties: |-
        configmap-property.username=configmap-test_user
        configmap-property.id=1234
        configmap-property.enable=true
        refresh-property.username=refresh-test_user
        refresh-property.id=4321
        refresh-property.enable=true
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: configmaptest
      namespace: default
      labels:
        app: configmaptest
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: configmaptest
      template:
        metadata:
          name: configmaptest
          namespace: default
          labels:
            app: configmaptest
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: configmaptest
          containers:
            - name: configmaptest
              image: configmaptest:latest
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: I found the solution at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/1482